# Can one use different database credentials for Doctrine migrations in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, permissions, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

How can one configure Symfony's `DoctrineMigrationsBundle` to use different database authentication credentials to its `DoctrineBundle`—or at very least, a different `DoctrineBundle` connection to that used elsewhere in the app?

We would like the app to connect to the database with only limited permissions, e.g. no ability to issue DDL commands such as  `CREATE`, `ALTER` or `DROP`.  However, migrations will need to execute such DDL commands and so should connect as a user with elevated permissions.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a very old post, but as it is the one which shows on a Google search on the subject, I add my solution, working with Symfony 4.

First, you just have to define a new database connection in `config/doctrine.yml` (a new entity manager is NOT needed):

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # This will be the connection used by the default entity manager
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '11.1'
                charset: UTF8
            migrations:
                # This will be the connection used for playing the migrations
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '11.1'
                charset: UTF8

    orm:
        # As usual...
```

You also have to define the `DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL` with the admin credentials in the `.env` file or in environnement variables:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://app_user:app_user_pass@localhost:5432/db
# Database url used for migrations (elevated rights)
DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL=postgresql://admin_user:admin_user_pass@localhost:5432/db
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Then, just execute your migrations with the `--db` option, passing the name of your new connection:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --db=migrations
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just [define a new entity manager](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) with the correct connection details and then use that entity manager when running migration commands

```
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:version --em=new_entity_manager
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced that this is what I want... the `--db-configuration` parameter looks more correct.  Could you help me understand how one should choose between the two?

Comment: I can't - I don't have direct experience with what you're trying to do - I just poked into the commands in the bundle and noticed they all accept an `--em` parameter